# ¿Que significa la diagonal invertida en corchetes [d\u]?

Tags: regex

Inicialmente tenia el problema de validar si una cadena de texto solo contenía letras u o d

Encontré un ejemplo: `new RegExp("^[d|u\d|u]"+$)`

Me funcionó pero no entiendo bien la expresión de diagonal invertida dentro de los corchetes.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar explicando esa expresión?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diagonal invertida significa dos cosas dependiendo el contexto en el que se encuentre:

- Define un escape de caracter especial para poder ser usado como literal en la `RegExp`.
- Significado especial dependiendo de letra o letras que lleve delante.

Por ejemplo, los caracteres `\` y `"` pueden escaparse dentro de un `string` usando `\` esto se hace para no tener que concatenar strings ni tampoco reemplazar el tipo de comillas que encierran la cadena, un ejemplo:

```js
console.log("\"Edgar \\ alan \\ poe\"");
```

De esta manera aunque usemos comillas dobles (`""`) para encerrar a nuestro texto podemos usarlas.

En una expresion regular es lo mismo, la diferencia es que para construir una regex no necesitamos ningun tipo de comillas ni al inicio ni al final:

```js
console.log(/\"Edgar \\ alan \\ poe\"/g);
```

Ahora bien, a lo que me refiero de que en ciertos casos puede tener un significado especial es porque en los casos donde en una `RegExp` le procedan ciertas letras en especifico el significado de acción de la `RegExp` cambia, como podemos verlo aquí en este enlace:

[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)

De hecho dentro de ese enlace podemos percatarnos que en tu expresión regular el significado de una de las partes donde se usa el símbolo `\` es distinto de simplemente poder `"escapar"` caracteres especiales:

```
new RegExp("^[d|u\d|u]"+$)
```

Mas especificamente esta parte de aquí:

```
\d
```

Donde según la pagina anterior mencionada esto **no significa que estamos escapando el caracter d**, significa:

> Coincide con un digito básico de 0-9 en el alfabeto latino, es
>   equivalente a: [0-9]

De hecho poniendo el fragmento entero que te interesa::

```
u\d
```

Esta expresión equivale a decir:

> Encuentra un valor que contenga el caracter `u` y seguido a el cualquier numero entre `0` y `9`.

Por lo que no hay que perderse, aquello que este alfrente del caracter `\`, si se trata de un carácter especial simplemente será escapado, pero si se trata de un carácter con un significado especifico en la `RegExp` no será escapado, sino que adquirirá las acciones o el significado especial de la `RegExp`.

Para saber cuales caracteres o conjunto de caracteres tiene un significado especial al colocarlos al lado de `\` debes mirar la tabla mencionada en la anterior pagina por si te interesa.

Puesto que mirar y explicar aquí todos y cada uno de ellos sería algo muy tedioso y largo, hay muchos significados que descubrir en las `RegExp`, esa pagina puede serte de ayuda en su descubrimiento.

Comment: Increíble,  me ayudó mucho tu respuesta..